# JS replace params in url when somenthing wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

i need a function to replace url params like this

users/?id=9&op=0?iu=0&t=9

to

users/?id=9&op=0&iu=0&t=9

can someone show me some piece of code to do that?

Comment: Why would you ever get in the position to have such silly URL? It's kind of like asking "Does anyone know a cheap way to remove poison from lunch?" The right answer is "Get a divorce", not "How to build a poison filter".

Comment: No, seriously, you program should never produce such an URL. And if a user enters it it's his own fool fault for tampering, as long as you show a nice error message or have good defaults, and don't crash and burn.

Comment: don't mind about that cause i'm using js interface then web service will do all kind of controls over passed params

Comment: Seriously, listen to @Amadan, don't try to fix the url after its already broken, fix the part of your application that spits out broken urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function fixURL(url){
    return url.replace(/\?/g,'&').replace('&','?');
}
fixURL('users.html?id=9&op=0?iu=0&t=9');
```

Comment: or are you serious this time?

Comment: I'm not kidding. Why do you think that? Try this function, it return the "clean" part of the url

Comment: uhm almost fixed ... cause the first ? should remain you are replacing that with a & instead :P

Comment: But it is. Here's the output: "users/?id=9&op=0&iu=0&t=9"

Comment: then i would like to do that only if are present in url more then 1 "?" chars  if only 1 ? is present not doing anything

Comment: omg sorry do not calculate the "/" parse only from ? to the end please ;9

Comment: or better i can have users/?... or users.html/?.. ;)

Comment: man, I don't understand why it's not working with you. Could you please explain better?

Comment: cause you do all after "/" in some cases i do not have users/?etc... but i have users.html?..etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function fixurl(url) {
   var urlarray = url.split('?');
   var parsed = urlarray[0] + '?' + urlarray[1] + '&' + urlarray[2];

   return parsed;
}
```

It turns `users/?id=9&op=0?iu=0&t=9` into `users/?id=9&op=0&iu=0&t=9`.

And `users.html/?id=9&op=0?iu=0&t=9` into `users.html/?id=9&op=0&iu=0&t=9`.